# Loking for a way to Store and process Raw NetCDF files (scientific data )on With HDFS and MapReduce or Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

i'm actually working on a spatial big data  project (NetCDF files) and i wanna store this data (netcdf files) on hdfs and process it with mapreduce or spark,so that users send queries sash as AVG,mean of vraibles by dimensions .

So i'm confised between 2 solutions :

1. convert netcdf files to csv or parquet and then use hadoop easly but ,from what i read ,it will take a lot of space and processing time
2. store the Raw netcdf files on Hdfs , but i didn't found a way for quering data from hdfs by mapreduce or spark in this case?

for the second solution did spatial Hadoop can help me ?

Comment: _from what i read ,it will take a lot of space and processing time_ - 1) Do not use CSV, ever, if Parquet is an option. 2) Yes, conversion will take time, but it will be much faster to query the data for analytics. 3) Why do you need Hadoop vs other options for storing data, like an actual database or [other spatial data formats](https://h3geo.org/) that [can be used with Spark](https://pypi.org/project/h3-pyspark/)?

Comment: thank you @OneCricketeer for you answer, so i used Hadoop (hdfs) because it's a distributed file system, so data can be easily queried. what do you think

Comment: S3( or Minio), Ceph, NFS, etc are all also distributed. In any case, the storage location  of the data won't help actually reading it. I've not heard NetCDF being a commonly used file format in Hadoop. You should definitely convert it, regardless of how slow that process may originally take. You'll only need to do that once, per file

Comment: @OneCricketeer H3's hexagonal grid system is not compatible with the typical NetCDF file, which stores gridded raster data. (An awkward transformation would be required to convert grid cells to hexagons.) DBMS's are usually not the best solution for working with raster data. So those are reasons not to use H3/spark.